# How to use @Transient with Micronaut Data and Kotlin properties that lack a backing field?

Tags: kotlin, micronaut-data

I'm moving to Micronaut Data JDBC and Kotlin from Spring Data JDBC and Java, and have trouble with `@Transient` on a Kotlin property which does not have a backing field.

Example code:

```
interface Foo {
    // @JvmDefault here had no effect on my problem
    // @Transient does not compile here
    val doodah: Boolean
        get() = /* some default implementation */
}

// Bar implements Foo for reasons unrelated to this question, part of an internal "microframework"
@Entity
@Introspected
@Table(name = "bar")
data class Bar(@Id var id: Long /* , more properties */) : Foo {
}

@JdbcRepository(dialect = POSTGRES)
interface BarRepository : CrudRepository<Bar, Long> {
}
```

At *runtime* I get a complaint from Postgres:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column child_record_.doodah does not exist
```

Hmmm, looks like Micronaut Data wants to serialize/deserialize the inherited property.  So I tried `@Transient` on the property, and compilation fails with:

```
This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate'
```

Suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface Foo {
    @get:javax.persistence.Transient
    val doodah: Boolean
        get() = /* some default implementation */
}
```

Comment: This also produces a compilation error:
```
This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate' and use site target '@get'
```

Comment: @binkley are you sure that you are using proper annotation class (javax.persistence.Transient)?

Comment: you are perfectly correct.  I had pulled in the Kotlin JVM annotation, not the persistence one.  Your answer is spot on, thank you!